# Calculate Mono/Complementary/Triadic/Analogous from specific color

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I know this is possible to be done using javascript, and I presume I could get the values to flash calling js, but I'm looking for any AS3 library/code that does the same.

js examples:
http://colorschemedesigner.com/js/color.js
http://design.geckotribe.com/colorwheel/colorwheel.js

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what exactly is your problem? what have you tried? where are you stuck?

you can basically copy the JavaScript that does the calculation and create a UI that goes with it. gradually you can start typing all variables and refactoring the code into classes, but for now it should compile just fine.

**edit:** there's none that I know of. maybe you could try working with [kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) using their [API](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/kulerdev/home), rather then implementing all the stuff on you own.

Comment: I though I was clear in my question:
"I'm looking for any AS3 library/code that does the same"
It means that i'm not (yet) trying to write the js to actionscript... I'm looking for code libraries.